# Converting function <T> from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this line of C# code that I want to change to VB.NET:

```
public static string functionx<RT>(RT req){}
```

Is the following the correct translation?

```
Public Function functionx(Of RT)(req As RT) As String
```

Comment: i need to know the equivalent in vb.net of public static string functionx<RT>(RT req){}

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

Close, but not quite. You need this:

```
Public Shared Function functionx(Of RT)(ByVal req As RT) As String
```

Comment: fwiw, [vbscript and company passed arguments ByRef by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), but [VB.Net passes ByVal by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx). However, even ByVal in .Net still just passes the value of the reference. @Random832

Answer (score 0):

To declare a generic method, you need:

```
Public Shared Function functionx(Of RT)(ByVal req As RT) As String
```

I don't know why, but you answered your own question with another question... Which is about the `typeof` equivalent in VB.NET:

In VB.NET `TypeOf` is not exactly the same as `typeof` in C#. See MSDN description:

> The `TypeOf` operator determines whether the run-time type of
>   objectexpression is compatible with typename. The compatibility
>   depends on the type category of typename. The following table shows
>   how compatibility is determined.

Its syntax is `TypeOf objectexpression Is typename`, and that's why error says that `Is` is expected.

You should use `GetType`:

```
    Dim serialzer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T)).Serialize(writer, req, ns)
```

Comment: @Random832 `ByVal` is by default, isn't it?

Comment: I think the editor adds it by default, but if you compile a file without it not written in visual studio ByRef is the default

Comment: hmm, that's not what MSDN says: 'The default in Visual Basic is to pass arguments by value.' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx