# Convert Array.FindIndex from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, indexof

I have this line in C#:

```
newline_pos = Array.FindIndex(buffer, offset, bytes, x => (x == NEWLINE));
```

Really have question in this part `x => (x == NEWLINE)`.

Please help me.

Comment: as i can use in vb.net

Comment: It's called a lambda expression, and you can use it in VB.NET, but the syntax is quite different.

Comment: I have no idea what to do

Comment: Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: try this `Dim newline_pos As Integer = Array.FindIndex(buffer, offset, bytes, Function(s) s = NEWLINE);`

Comment: If you want to convert the code from C# to VB, there's plenty of free online converter available.  If you want to understand what lambda expression are, you should search for a tutorial.  In both case, google will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Lambda ( => )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970219/c-sharp-lambda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go here: http://converter.telerik.com and convert the C# to VB.Net:

**C#:**

```
x => (x == NEWLINE)
```

**VB.Net:**

```
(Function(x) x = NEWLINE)
```

Comment: @Jearca Using the converter will solve your other question **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643644/converting-function-t-to-c-sharp-to-vb-net)**. Dont forget to mark correct answers (the holo tickbox under the voting buttons.

Comment: thanks is the correct lambda expression the problem is x is a byte and NEWLINE is a char, so i have a error i need to know if that expression is correct?? `Function(x) x.CompareTo(NEWLINE)`

Comment: VB.Net uses *implicit* casting, it doesn't require *Explicit* casting. So in VB.Net you dont worry about converting the byte to char to test for equality. Only in C# do you have to *explicitly* cast types.

Comment: ok, but i have a error and i cant compile, for that i need know if i can use `Function(x) x.CompareTo(NEWLINE)`

Comment: Copy the entire function (not just the line with the `Array.FindIndex`) into http://converter.telerik.com and it will solve the conversion for you :) Its a good way to learn either C# or VB.Net when you only know one of the languages and wish to learn the other.